# problem Set-cookie, python requests session, __Secure-next-auth.session-token

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, setcookie

its the fragment of Python code:

```
credentialsPayload = {
    'username':email,
    'password':password,
    'redirect': 'false',
    'csrfToken':csrf,
    'callbackUrl':'https://app.leonardo.ai/auth/login',
    'json': 'true'
  }
  
  headers = {
    'Set-Cookie': 'foo=bar; Path=/; Secure',
    'User-Agent': 'AppleWebkit/'+str(535.36+random.random()),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cookie':'_ga=GA1.1.2124089843.'+str(random.randint(1690000000,1691135851))+'; isMinor=false; referralAlreadySet=true; isPatron=false; _ga_55MHQJ6K8W=GS1.1.1691138392.2.1.1691138551.60.0.0'
  }
  # this dont need 'Authorization':'Bearer SOMETHING'
  response = s.post('https://app.leonardo.ai/api/auth/callback/credentials?', json=credentialsPayload, headers=headers)
  print(response.cookies) # returns <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie __Host-next-auth.csrf-token=SOMEUSELESSTOKEN for app.leonardo.ai/>, <Cookie __Secure-next-auth.callback-url=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.leonardo.ai%2Fauth%2Flogin for app.leonardo.ai/>]>
```

but I it should not return `__Host-next-auth.csrf-token and __Secure-next-auth.callback-url` and I need cookies like:

```
__Secure-next-auth.session-token.0=eyJhbGci....Jff54fb, __Secure-next-auth.session-token.1=6Mo5g...QJbvpbog
```

(there are very long)

And I just can't get these.

In response headers I see the stroke Set-Cookie:__Secure-next-auth.session-token.0=eyJh... but i dont receive cookies.

How can I get this data using the lib requests (dont using Selenium)

1

s = requests.Session()

so cookies must be saved from one request to other.

2

I use in headers 'Set-Cookie': 'foo=bar; Path=/; Secure', (for initial state for Set-Cookie). And I dont know should me add 'Domain' in 'Set-Cookie' and with which value

3

Maybe problem with auth or callback-url, or should I get the login page (I tried it) or it can be because it use Baggage in request headers....

So I don't know what Can I do to fix the problem.